# Android Getting Error ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, activitynotfoundexception

I'm new here in android programming but it seems I can't find my error I need your help

Every time I log in and click the button `btnLogin` app stops.

Login class

```
public class DocLogin extends Fragment {

ImageView ivIcon;
TextView tvItemName, tvRegister;
EditText user, pass;
Button btnLogin;
SQLController dbcon;
SessionManager session;

public DocLogin() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doc_log_in, container, false);

    session = new SessionManager(getActivity());

    dbcon = new SQLController(getActivity());
    dbcon.open();

    // Log in
    user = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etUser);
    pass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    // Sign up
    tvRegister = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRegDoc);
    tvRegister.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    tvRegister.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DocReg());
            ft.commit();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // btnLogin onClickListener
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            dbcon = new SQLController(getActivity());
            dbcon.open();


            Log.v("LoginDetails", user.getText().toString() + "../.."
                    + pass.getText().toString());
            Cursor cur = dbcon.getuser_information(user.getText()
                    .toString(), pass.getText().toString());
            if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DocProfile());
                ft.commit();
            } else {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity()).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Login Error");
                alertDialog
                        .setMessage("Doctor Code and Password does not match");
                alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // dismiss dialog
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }

        }
    });

    return view;
}

}
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
06-23 14:11:16.483: E/Trace(4864): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.droid/com.droid.DocLogin}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at com.droid.SessionManager.checkLogin(SessionManager.java:41)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at com.droid.DocProfile.onCreateView(DocProfile.java:43)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-23 14:11:27.783: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But after declaring `DocLogin` class in `AndroidManifest`

This is the error

```
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.droid/com.droid.DocLogin}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.droid.DocLogin cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.droid.DocLogin cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
06-23 14:09:53.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4791):     ... 11 more
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: you need to add your DocLogin Activity in Manifest of application tag.

Comment: I already did but it gives me the 2nd error

Comment: Try to extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity in DocLogin class.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.droid.DocLogin cannot be cast to android.app.Activity` you can't start fragment as activity

Comment: you have declared the fragment in manifest file??

Comment: then how to get the context ?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes and gives me the 2nd error

Comment: @user3766257 wrong fragment is not an activity

Comment: you can use `getActivity()` in fragment to getting `context` of activity class

Comment: @shayanpourvatan if I extend it in FragmentActivity how to get the context ?

Comment: get context in FragmentActivity? use `this`. context in Fragment ? as I said use `getActivity()`;

Comment: try `FragmenActivityName.this`

Answer (score 0):

`DocLogin` is Fragment not an `Activity`.

Add DocLogin `Fragment` to `Activity` then declare that `Activity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`file

Answer (score 0):

The ActivityNotFound exception is shown because it cannot find the said activity. Instead of the class that you've created, create an Android Activity of the same and declare it in the Android Manifest.

Comment: but I need it in `Fragment` im using `DrawerLayout` for navigation menu

Answer (score 0):

ActivitynotFound exception is because of the absence of activity declaration inside AndroidManifest.xml file.

I think your Activity class is DocProfile. Make sure it extends FragmentActivity and add the DocLogin fragment to the DocProfile Activty.

Comment: if I will use `FragmentActivity`  how to get the context ?

Comment: there is function getActivity() for getting the activity. The better way is to write the onAttach() method and assign the activity to some variable and you can use that inside the fragment entirely

Answer (score 0):

DocLogin is not extending activity. so remove fragment and extends activity

If you want DocLogin to extend fragment then create one more activity and add view to that activity which is return by DocLogin like shown below.

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

DocLogin doclogin;

```
//In oncreate
 doclogin = new DocLogin();
 setcontentview(doclogin);
```

}

Please add your Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml.

When you want to making new activity, you should register it in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: after trying ur suggestion I'm getting error on `setContentView` it says The method setContentView(int) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (DocLogin)

Comment: ok. Instead of Fragment, extend FragmentActivity and try in your class; dont do above method which creating one activity and adding view to that activity.

Answer (score 0):

as your logcat says:

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class 
{com.droid/com.droid.DocLogin}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

## Reason

you havn't declare com.droid.DocLogin in your manifest file.

declare this activitry in menifest will remove this exception.

// also your getting one more exception which is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.droid.DocLogin cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

this is because **DocLogin** is a  fragment not a activity,also you can use getactivity() as a context for the fragment.